# Drupal blocks are syncing?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to enable a new theme on a site running Drupal 6.16. I enable it fine, it has its own namespace in the theme and theme registry.

However when you go to the Blocks section, changing a block here will affect that blocks placement in all the other themes, and vice versa.

Is this normal behavior? Where should I begin looking to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed normal behavior.

It's purpose is to allow the website designers/maintainers to put their customized content into a block, and place the block where they would like it. Then, when they apply a skin, or several, that block is skinned, but it's placement and content does not change.

Comment: So even if I go into another theme, and make a new block and/or move it, it moves those changes across all themes?

Comment: Yes, that is the intended behavior.

Comment: Note that this is only the case when themes share region names.

Comment: Correct, you can define your own regions in custom themes, however the large majority of default and other downloadable themes do use the same standard/default region names.

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen this happen before now. The secondary theme is a clone of the first one (custom) but none of the region names are changed.